# What constitutes as a minor sentence?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

According to [this](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-a-minor-sentence-1691393), a minor sentence is defined as *a fragmented, elliptical, or incomplete sentence or **clause** that still conveys meaning*.

But I've always thought that minor sentences were incomplete sentences which could not be clauses as they lack a subject and a verb? (sometimes they have one but not the other);

> Just a minute.
>
> The more, the merrier.
>
> No pain, no gain.

Answer (score 1):

I think, that the website you're citing is talking about informal speech, where the rest of the sentence can be derived from the fragment.  It says an incomplete/fragmented sentence/clause, which might not have all the elements of a clause/sentence, but still conveys a complete thought.  Also, you can have a clause that isn't a sentence, such as "because I'm annoyed", which has a subject(I), and a verb('m), but still isn't a sentence because it's a dependent clause: again, in informal language, you can infer the rest of the sentence from what came before.